# Upload excel file in javascript and get the object

Tags: javascript

I want to upload ecel read the content and add those content in the data table .

This is how i am trying to do using this reference https://javacodepoint.com/convert-excel-file-data-to-json-in-javascript/

```
    $('#uploadFile').on('click', async function () {
      var files = document.getElementById('stocksform').files;
      if(files.length==0){
        alert("Please choose any file...");
        return;
      }
      var filename = files[0].name;
      var extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".")).toUpperCase();
      if (extension == '.XLS' || extension == '.XLSX') {
        var jsonResult  =  excelFileToJSON(files[0]);
        console.log(jsonResult);
      }else{
          alert("Please select a valid excel file.");
      }
    
    $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
    });
```

The  excelFileToJSON

```
    function excelFileToJSON(file){
     try {
       
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                type : 'binary'
            });
            var result = {};
            workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
                var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                if (roa.length > 0) {
                    result[sheetName] = roa;
                }
            });
            console.log(result);
            return result ; 
           }
        }catch(e){
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
```

Issue is when i am running it the below code gets (from the above code) executed with 'undefined' in the console

```
    var jsonResult  =  excelFileToJSON(files[0]);
        console.log(jsonResult);
```

and there after i can see the result printed from this line inside the excelFileToJSON .

```
        console.log(result);
```

There is some issue with reader.onload , that returns undefined but after sometime it provides the result . What can be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `await` until the `onload` function execute, you can achieve that by using `Promise` constructor, and `resolve` when `onload` execute with the `result`.

```
function excelFileToJSON(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                type: "binary",
            });
            var result = {};
            workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function (sheetName) {
                var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(
                    workbook.Sheets[sheetName]
                );
                if (roa.length > 0) {
                    result[sheetName] = roa;
                }
            });
            resolve(result);
        };
    });
}
   

async function executor() {
   var jsonResult  =  await excelFileToJSON(files[0]);
   console.log(jsonResult);
}
```